# Oracle 11gr2 on debian

Tags: oracle

I want to install oracle 11g r2 on my laptop(ASUS G71GX-7s023k) on crunchbang(a debian distro)

I added the users required and installed all required packages,
but every time i try to run runInstaller , i get the following error:

```
/media/data/database/install/.oui: 2: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running bash or dash?  A couple of gotcha from certain linux distro is that /bin/sh was replace with dash and it resulted in certain bourne shell script borking itself.  Double check to make sure that your /bin/sh is bash/bourne and not dash.   plus don't forget to run the runinstaller application with "-ignoreSysPrereqs".

Answer (score 0):

Oracle database 11gR2 is only certified for Oracle Linux, Asianux, RedHat EL and Suse Linux server. Crunchbag ( what version? )is not even Debian but a Debian based distro. You don't have to take the certification matrix too serious for personal usage (Fedora is fine), but what you're trying to do is asking for trouble.

My advise : don't do it.

Alternatives:

a. Use a virtual machine

b. Put oracle database software on a server somewhere and only run the client on your laptop.